# Entity Framework : A query that works in EF5 but not in EF6

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I have this code :

```
Partial Public Class Myobj
  Public Property id As Integer
  Public property name as string
  Public Overridable Property chld As ICollection(Of chld) = New HashSet(Of chld) 
   End Class


 Partial Public Class Myobj
      <NotMapped> Public Property vls As integer
End Class

Partial Public Class chld
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property date1 as DateTime
    Public Property quantity as Integer
    Public Property ParentID as integer
    Public Overridable Property MyObj1 As MyObj
End Class 

Public Class PseudoMyObj
    Inherits MyObj
End Class
```

Now on my form, I have this code :

```
Dim dt1 as DateTime=CDate("08/08/2014")
 Dim list1 = (From t In context.MyObj Select New With { _
      .Parent = New PseudoMyObj With {  _
      .chld =  (From t2 in t.chld.AsQueryable.Where(Function(t3) t3.Date1>=dt1) Select t2), _
      .vls=(t.chld.AsQueryable.Where(Function(t2) t2.date1<dt1).Select(Function(t3) t3.quantity).DefaultIfEmpty.Sum()) _
}).ToList

Dim mylist as IEnumerable(of MyObj)=list1.Select(Function(t2) t2.Parent)
```

This is working on Entity Framework 5 , but not in  Entity Framework 6.
Why ?
Thank you !

Comment: what is being returned, and what do you expect to be returned?

Comment: In the EF5 , all is working , in the Mylist, all the Myobj have the .vls not-mapped property filled with the right sum values , and each of Myobj has the correct collection of child's according to the query where clause. In the EF6 , the .vls is always 0.